# Error in calculation of expectation of function chi square random variable

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, probability-distributions, substitution

> Suppose that $X$ follows a chi-square distribution $\chi_n^2$ and that $Y=\sqrt{2X}$. Find the pdf of $Y$ and show that $\mathbb{E}(Y) = \frac{\Gamma((n+1)/2)}{\Gamma(n/2)}$.

I have calculated the pdf using the change of variable formula as

$$f_Y(y) = \frac{y^{n-1} e^{-y^2/4}}{2^{n-1} \Gamma(n/2)}$$

Now 
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}(Y)
 &= \int^{\infty}_{0} y \cdot \frac{y^{n-1} e^{-y^2/4}}{2^{n-1} \Gamma(n/2)}dy \\
 &= \int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{y^{n} e^{-y^2/4}}{2^{n-1} \Gamma(n/2)}dy \\
 &= \int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{y^{n-1}e^{-y^2/4}}{2^{n-2}\Gamma(n/2)} \frac{y}{2}dy \\
 &= \int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{2^{n-1}(y^2/4)^{(n-1)/2}e^{-y^2/4}}{2^{n-2}\Gamma(n/2)}
\frac{y}{2}dy \\
 &= \int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{2(y^2/4)^{(n+1)/2-1}e^{-y^2/4}}{\Gamma(n/2)} \frac{y}{2}dy.
\end{split}
$$

Finally using the definition that $\Gamma(\alpha) = \int^{\infty}_{0} x^{\alpha-1}e^{-t}dt$ and making the substitution $t=y^2/4 \Leftrightarrow dt = y/2\,dy$ we get

$$
\mathbb{E}(Y)
 = \frac{2}{\Gamma(n/2)} \int^\infty_0  t^{(n+1)/2-1}e^{-t}\,dt
 = \frac{2\Gamma((n+1)/2)}{\Gamma(n/2)}
$$
which is off by a factor of $2$ of what they get. Where is the mistake?

Comment: One also has $$ \operatorname E Y = \int_0^\infty \sqrt{2x} f_X(x)\, dx. $$

Comment: ... which gives the same answer as you get (but much faster). So there must be a mistake in the problem formulation (I suspect there should be $\sqrt{X/2}$ not $\sqrt{2X}$).

Comment: Wikipedia's mean for the [chi distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution) also seems to suggest the problem has been scaled in the wrong direction

Comment: Here's a quick comment; maybe I'll be back later.
$$
f_X(x) \, dx = \frac 1 {\Gamma(n/2)} \left( \frac x 2 \right)^{(n/2)-1} e^{-x/2} \, \left( \frac{dx} 2 \right) \quad \text{for } x>0.
$$
$$ {} $$

$$
\begin{align}
f_Y(y) & = \frac d {dy} \Pr(Y\le y) = \frac d {dy} \Pr(\sqrt{2X} \le y) \\ {} \\
& = \frac d {dy} \Pr\left( X \le \frac{y^2} 2 \right) \\ {} \\
& =  \frac d{dy} \int_0^{y^2/2} f_X(x)\,dx \\ {} \\
& = f_X(y^2/2)\cdot y \\ {} \\
& = \frac 1 {\Gamma(n/2)} \left( \frac {y^2/2} 2 \right)^{n/2-1} e^{-y^2/2} \cdot \frac y 2
\end{align}
$$

Comment: thanks it could be theres a mistake in the book i have seen some before